# how to get the content from trial() HYPEROPT to model?

Tags: model, hyperopt

basically, train and evaluate the model with BAYESIAN-OPT using HYPEROPT , after that  save the trials using pickle and now want to get the best-hyperparameter from trial to my model ,can anyone tell me how to get the content in trial() from HYPEROPT to a model???